# Set the system language

Tags: java, windows, locale

I need to setup a text field and it's input language to be Malayalam-India in Windows.

I tried with this code:

```
System.setProperty("user.language","MY");
System.setProperty("user.country","IN");
```

But it didn't succeed.

How can I set the system language in Java?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you change the input language? Do you mean the keyboard as an input device?

Comment: You are (apparently) not trying to set the system language.  The code indicates that you are actually trying to set the language for your application.

Comment: Keyboard input to a text field shoud be in Malayalam Language.
How can i change to malayalam?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the "user.language" and "user.country" values need to be passed as VM Arguments at startup and NOT set using `System.setProperty()` at runtime, since `System.setProperty()` will not influence the default locale that is already in memory. If you need to change the default locale during runtime, use `Locale.setDefault();`

```
// THIS WON'T WORK - IF YOU NEED TO SET DEFAULT LOCALE AT RUNTIME, USE  Locale.setDefault()
System.setProperty("user.language","MY");
System.setProperty("user.country","IN");
```

Set Locale first and change the system propery

```
Locale.setDefault( new Locale("MY"));
System.setProperty("user.language","MY");
Locale.setDefault( new Locale("IN") );
System.setProperty("user.language","IN");
```

Reference: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-via-system-properties.html